# Problems with installing, package 'minet' is available as a source package but not as a binary

Tags: r, statistics, rstudio, bioconductor

I am currently trying install a package from Bioconductor, I got the following message

```
     BioC_mirror: http://bioconductor.org
     Using Bioconductor version 2.14 (BiocInstaller 1.14.2), R version 3.1.0.
     Installing package(s) 'minet'
     package 'minet' is available as a source package but not as a binary

     Warning message:
     package 'minet' is not available (for R version 3.1.0)
```

The package is called "minet", avaliable at http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/minet.html

Comment: well, did you try biocLite("minet", type="source")

Comment: `biocLite("minet")` followed by `library("minet")` works here on R 3.1.0 with Bioconductor 2.14.

Comment: Your Mac OS is Mavericks, and minet is not (yet) available for Mavericks (as indicated on the page you cite). This is because there is a [segmentation fault](http://bioconductor.org/checkResults/2.14/bioc-LATEST/minet/morelia-checksrc.html) that the package author has not yet addressed.

Answer (score 2):

As @MartinMorgan points out, the package fails to build on Mavericks, and won't be available until the maintainer fixes it.

I have contacted the maintainer with a fix, so it should be resolved soon.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes, I couldn't leave it as a comment, which seemed like the best thing. But what, then, was OP's question? The package has C++ code that leads to a segfault. I tracked it down to code that yields undefined behavior, and contacted the author with the problem and a fix. But the segfault is not pertinent to what I saw as OP's question (which I couldn't refine because I can't comment): "why can't I install the package, and when will it be fixed?"

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source code (probably tar.gz) and install it through your RStudio. This is a tutorial of what you could do:

http://outmodedbonsai.sourceforge.net/InstallingLocalRPackages.html

It's so simple, but I didn't get the answer so easily.